# How to test DB queries when DB schema in question has lots of constraints?

Tags: unit-testing, jpa, fixtures, xunit

Background:

- moderate DB schema (some 70 tables)
- with lots of foreign keys and other constraints (not null etc.) between them
- a shared DB fixture for all the tests
- some simple tear-down logic which truncates "touched" tables after each test and puts there whatever was there before the test
- the DB is queried by JPA/Hibernate/Toplink or some other object-relational mapping solution

Now, the big issue is we want to add some records to the DB we now have to do this manually, i.e. through sql scripts (which are executed before the test in question).
This leads to a [Mystery Guest](http://xunitpatterns.com/Obscure%20Test.html#Mystery%20Guest) problem in almost each and every test we have.

How would You deal with that?

My thoughts are as follow:

- creating a fresh fixture for each and every test would be an overkill since we have really lots of constraints
- an alternative would be to create some oracle, that, given a stub of an object, would return an object ready to put into the DB, i.e. such that doesn't violate any constraint. 
  This nice solution, of course,  is not beloved by our managers since we would have to spend a bit of time on creating such a beast.